# What does contextual type 'MGTransitioningOptions' cannot be used with array literal mean?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, struct

At one point I'm guessing before Swift 3 the following line of code used to compile but now it does not:

```
var directions: MGTransitioningOptions = [.DirectionUp]
```

It gives the following error: "contextual type 'MGTransitioningOptions' cannot be used with array literal"

Here is the code for the struct where MGTransitioningOptions is created:

```
struct MGTransitioningOptions: OptionSet {
    internal let rawValue: Int
    init(rawValue: Int) {self.rawValue = rawValue}
    static let DirectionUp = MGTransitioningOptions(rawValue: 1<<1)
    static let DirectionDown = MGTransitioningOptions(rawValue: 1<<2)
    static let DirectionLeft = MGTransitioningOptions(rawValue: 1<<3)
    static let DirectionRight = MGTransitioningOptions(rawValue: 1<<4)
    static let AlphaChange = MGTransitioningOptions(rawValue: 1<<5)
    static let BlurBackground = MGTransitioningOptions(rawValue: 1<<5)
    static let Dissolve = MGTransitioningOptions(rawValue: 1<<6)
    static let Interactive = MGTransitioningOptions(rawValue: 1<<7)
}
```

Comment: Are you using Swift 3?

Comment: @JAL yes, I'm using the beta Xcode version 8 so its attempting to convert all of my code to swift 3 I believe.